# Can you sell part of a pack to buy another pack in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, dnd-adventurers-league

Adventurer's League player guide:

> **Selling Equipment.** You can sell any mundane equipment that your character possesses using the normal rules in the PHB.
>
> **Purchasing Equipment.** You can purchase any equipment found in the PHB with your starting gold.

Starting character is a wizard, who takes scholar's pack.  Scholar's pack contains a "book of lore" (worth 25 gold), which I assume serves no real use in AL?  Book sells for 12.5, buy an explorer's pack for 10, sell the extra backpack for 1.  You now have an explorer's pack plus some free ink and paper, plus 3.5 gp.

I honestly can't see any reason to take a scholar's pack and not also buy an explorer's pack, you're going to at the very least need rations, so can you just do it this way if your background doesn't give you 10 gold?

Comment: Also related: [Can I buy a new item with gold obtained in adventurers league character creation?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110962/can-i-buy-a-new-item-with-gold-obtained-in-adventurers-league-character-creatio?rq=1)